# Add a video to a ReactJS app and make it visible on the view

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am currently generating a landing page, and I have been trying to figure it out how to add a video in multiple formats (for browser compatibility)

I am new in the ReactJS world, your help will be truly appreciated!

Here is my code:

I generated a component for the video (I'm not sure if this is the best thing I could do)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import video1 from "./video/vd1.mp4";
import video2 from "./video/vd2.ogv";
import video3 from "./video/vd3.webm";

class Video extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <video src={video1} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Video;
```

And I have also this file that is where I want to place the video:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { PageHeader } from "react-bootstrap";
import Video from "./Video";

class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PageHeader className="title">
          <video src={Video} autoPlay="true" />
          <small>Welcome to</small> <br />
          Profile Pulse
        </PageHeader>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```

Of course, this way of doing it is giving me zero results, so what would it be the best way to make the video appear on my landing page?

Answer (score 4):

This should work,

Change `<video>` tag of Video component to

```
<video src={video1} width="600" height="300" controls="controls" autoplay="true" />
```

Change `<Content>`'s `<video src={Video} autoPlay="true" />` to

```
<Video />
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work...Add the different formats as sources in the video-tag

```
<Video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src={video1}>
   <source src={video2}>
   <source src={video2}>
</Video>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { PageHeader } from "react-bootstrap";
    import Video from "./Video";

    class Content extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <PageHeader className="title">
              <Video />  //Here just call your Video Component
              <small>Welcome to</small> <br />
              Profile Pulse
            </PageHeader>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default Content;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried that and the video stills not showing up, will that be maybe because of the format? I know, because I've done that before when using HTML and CSS and I insert other formats as well for browser compatibility, those formats are: **ogv** and **webm**, do you think that might help the video to be displayed, and how could that be implemented in the components?

Comment: try with image first , if this structure worked with image , than it will definitely work for video.

Comment: But how would it be the structure with image?

Comment: instead of video use image , import a image as you imported a video in video component and other will be same just use image instead of video , if image appear in out , this will work for video too

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./Training.css";
import Video from "../../img/myvideo.mp4"

const Training = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container-fluid p-0">
        <video id="bannerVideo" autoPlay muted loop>
          <source src={Video} type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Training;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).